# Postgresql: split cell containing column names (WHERE Metacolumn='col1;col2;col3;..') apart into array to dynamically generate INSERT statement

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, dynamic-sql

In Postgresql (and Sybase ADS), I am making my own trigger-based multimaster replication across both platforms which must dynamically handle various composite keys and sometimes no PK on certain tables. To make it easiest, I am trying to auto generate the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE  where the user can choose which columns they want to copy over by listing column names in a cell separated by semicolon.

-"`SELECT Address, city, us_state, zipcode FROM public.place;`" would be a table that needs to replicate. 
-The Metatable for Publication/Subscriptions would have a cell containing '`Address;city;us_state;zipcode`'. 
-I am using Insert/update/delete triggers to capture new row data and want to use the columns to dynamically make a statement like 
"`insert into place (Address,city,us_state,zipcode) VALUES (NEW.Address,NEW.city,NEW.us_state,NEW.zipcode);`" which can be read and executed on the desination via script. I will do the same action for UPDATE and DELETE, using OLD prefix in the UPDATE and DELETE generated statements where needed.

I am not looking for someone to do a bunch of work, but to give an idea of any functions, logic and statements involved. Thank you for any ideas or advice.

Comment: Just an observation: it looks like you are trying to make a database do the job of an application. Your life would be simpler both now and in the future if you left the database to handle persistence and put the “smarts” in the app layer, possibly using a distributed cache. Consider also if you should even create such functionality, especially since nobody else has.

Answer (score 0):

You can split a String and create an Array using the `regexp_split_to_array` function.

Probably something like: `regexp_split_to_array(metacolumn, ';')`

More info about string functions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-string.html